# Having troubles connecting to Wordpress login page using Mamp

Tags: wp-admin, login

I have just downloaded Mamp and WordPress to my Macos X and I would like to be able to create and store some WordPress sites on this host. I have encountered a problem connecting to WordPress login page. I think it's something to do with my Apache. I have really tried everything, this is very frustrating. Whenever I try to put in the localhost link:

> http://localhost:8888/Sites/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php

a "not found" page pops up saying that it's not found on the server. WordPress and mamp are not connecting for some reason. Any advise for this would be much appreciated. THANKS

Comment: By default MAMP looks to Applications/MAMP/htdocs for your sites as what MAMP calls the "document root" (in this case probably your 'wordpress' directory). Either way, wherever you have your document root configured make sure that each site is contained in a separate folder and not nested. So in your document root, each separate folder will be a separate install of Wordpress. (htdocs/wpsite1, htdocs/wpsite2 etc.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I moved the WordPress files out of htdocs and into my directory which I am supposed to do. I don't have any sites added yet. I am trying to connect wordpress first which is located in a folder called "wordpress" which is located in "Sites" in my root directory. Any reason why "Not Found" would be showing up still? Do you think it has to do with my Apache not working? thanks

Comment: make sure mysql and apache are running first. you can see this in the mamp gui. to be extra certain restart your computer and launch mamp. move the folder 'wordpress' out of your 'Sites' folder and into your root directory. you should then be able to access your site's admin at localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin

Comment: Great thanks, i downloaded wordpress again and placed it in my directory and finally it connected.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!